# Optimizing speculative trading

Tags: combinatorics

I was going to post this in the RPG stack exchange, since the game involved is Mongoose Traveller, but then I realized this probably better fits here, since I believe it's a variation on the knapsack problem.

My team and I are going to engage in some speculative trading, buying goods on one world, then jumping to another world to sell them. Hopefully, this will yield us insane amounts of filthy lucre. I'm fairly sure I can turn a profit on just intuition, but I'd like to see if there is some algorithm to determine what kind of trades we should be making in order to maximize our income, given our constraints.

Our constaints are:

- our cargo capacity, measured in displacement tons (dtons),
- our initial amount of money, measured in imperial credits (Cr).

There is a large list of goods we can buy. They can be simplified to have two important characteristics:

- the price we can buy them at (Cr/dton),
- the price we can sell them at (Cr/dton).

The last two are variable, but given my character's obscene skill modifiers for trading, they're guaranteed to be available cheaper than they would sell for later.

For example, using my gut feeling and playing it safe, I could fill my entire 76 dton cargo hold with basic machine parts, buying them for 2500 Cr/dton, and sell them for 30000 Cr/dton. This would require a fairly paltry 190000 Cr to do; the initial amount is flexible, we can take a short-term, usurious loan if we need to.

What would be the general approach to solving this problem?

Comment: I thought this was trivial but that was because I didn't interpret the question right. I will try and think about the correct answer later but I'm now a little more convinced that this is a version of the knapsack problem. If the goods are not arbitrarily divisible this might actually be hard. I can't really even see that it is in NP though it seems like possibly it should be.

Comment: Hah turns out knapsack really is only NP-Hard. So it might actually not be in NP.

Comment: @DRF The goods are discrete in 1 dton amounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [Integer Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) problem which can't be easily solved without some computation. Even though, most probably the list is small enough so you can write it down and solve it.

Basically, you'll have the following.

$\begin{align}
\max &\ x\\
x & = \sum_i x_i(S_i-B_i)\\
\sum_ix_iW_i &\leq C\\
\sum_i x_iB_i & \leq T\\
x_i& \geq 0
\end{align}$

Where $S_i$ is the Selling value per unit (not ton) of good $i$, $B_i$ it's buying value and $C$ the cargo capacity, $T$ is total budget; $W_i$ is the weight of each unit and $x_i$ the number of units bought.

[Using Google](https://www.google.es/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=solve%20integer%20programming) you're able to find ways to solve this problem. The answer basically depends completely on the values of the goods.

*Edit to add total budget.*